# nginx redirect http to https with custom port server

Tags: nginx

i have some question about using nginx.
as you can see the title, i am trying to redirect http to https.

before read nginx code, i want to tell you that the main server made by node.js, and using https with custom port(i.e. 3000).

so what i gonna do is when user type "http://mywebsite.com" on the browser, redirect to "https://mywebsite.com".

this is my nginx code:

```
# http://mywebsite.com: redirect to https
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# https
# redirect to 3000 port with https!
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mywebsite.com
    root ...

    ...

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remove_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
}

...
```

this is the first time to using nginx so it is really hard to me. it will be very appreciate it that help me. thx!

Comment: why don't you just replace return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; with return 301 https://$server_name:3000$request_uri; and listen 443 ssl; with listen 3000 ssl; ?

Comment: if i do that, what about "https:\//mywebsite.com"? that should be not work. i want redirect to "https:\//mywebsite.com:3000" also.

Comment: Do you want both 443 and 3000 ports to work? If only 3000 - try the small changes I mentioned

Comment: i want to do: "HTTP(80)" -> REDIRECT -> "HTTPS(443)" -> FORWARD TO -> "3000". before setting was "HTTP(80)" -> FORWARD TO -> "3000".  i want both connect with http and https. did i ask something none understandable? sorry for this. i'm bad at english ;(

Comment: ok guys, i found something more basic problem. if user connect to "https:\//mywebsite.com", should be forwarded to "https:\//127.0.0.1:3000", but it isn't. i think this is the actual problem. forward http to http is back issue i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need redirect all https to https, you must write co your global config:

`server {
    listen      80;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}`